# How to host a new site in Turnkey Linux?

Tags: hosting, turnkey-linux, lamp

On one of my server, [TurnKey Linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/) is installed.

How to host a new site http://example.com/ in it?

In Windows system we usually setup sites with IIS server, how to do it here and how to assign a separate FTP account for that newly created site.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you installed the Turnkey LAMP appliance rather than one of their other products?

Well, I guess you start at the [Web based admin pages](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/screenshots/lamp-turnkey-control-panel)

Turnkey Linux is derived from Ubuntu so you can probably also follow [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.10/ubuntu/serverguide/C/httpd.html) if you are comfortable with the command line and have read an overview of Apache concepts.

If you don't have DNS configured to associate "exmple.com" with the IP-address of your server, you should start with that. Is this for LAN use (i.e. personal or "Intranet") or external use (i.e. an Internet facing server behind a firewall/router)?

---

EDIT

Have you read the documentation for Apache and for ftpd? which parts are you having problems with?

Are you editing configuration files directly or are you using a GUI tool? If so which one?

Comment: This is for external use (internet).

Comment: For external Internet access, if, for example, the server is behind a firewall using network address translation (NAT), the DNS must be configured to associate "example.com" with (one of) the external address(es) of the firewall and the firewall must be configured to forward traffic to the internal address of the server (e.g. by port-forwarding or some other means). But if hosted in-house, you'd get the web-server working for clients on the internal LAN.